# What does View method getId() return?

Tags: android

What is the co-relation between View's getId() method and the id defined in the XML file? Is there any? My IDs look like this: "field1", "field2"... This digits at the end are very important for my application and I need to retrieve them. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What is the co-relation between View's getId() method and the id defined in the XML file?

`getId()` returns the `android:id` value, or the value you set via `setId()`.

> My IDs look like this: "field1", "field2"

In your XML, they may look like `@+id/field1` and `@+id/field2`. Those are allocating ID resources, which are turned into numbers at compile time. These are the numbers you refer to in Java code as `R.id.field1` and `R.id.field2`.

> This digits at the end are very important for my application and I need to retrieve them. Is there any way to do it?

Have a big switch statement comparing the ID to `R.id.field1`, etc. Or, set up a `HashMap` to map between the `getId()` values and your "very important" numbers. Or, find some other solution that does not involve magic names on your ID values.

Answer (score 21):

To get resource id name:

```
res.getResourceEntryName(view.getId())
```

You will get "field1"

Comment: where res = Resources

Answer (score 2):

> What is the co-relation between View's getId() method and the id
>   defined in the XML file? Is there any?

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29):

> Returns this view's identifier.
>
> Related XML Attributes
>
> android:id
>
> Returns
>
> a positive integer used to identify the view or NO_ID if the view has no ID

Answer (score 1):

It returns a positive number which android studio gives to every component of android app for backup use, In case the developer does not provide the ID of that component, android studio uses that number as a unique ID for that component.

Comment: int id = view.getId();

Comment: Will return the ID of the View