# How to get radio button's id and convert to string?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working in Android Studio and am trying to get the ID of the selected radio button and then store the ID in a string. Is this possible?

I have tried replacing the .getText() method below with .getId() but it wont let me store it as a string:

```
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId)
        {
            RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
            String text = checkedRadioButton.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getId()` returns an `int` - which, like all [primitive types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), does not have a `toString()` (or any other) method. This is because, while all Objects have a `toString()` method, primitives are not Objects - but lucky for you, Java provides [wrapper classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) that *are* Objects for all primitive type. In the case of `int`, the corresponding wrapper class is called `Integer`:

```
 String text = (Integer)checkedRadioButton.getId().toString();
```

Here, we're explicitly casting the `int` returned by `getId()` to an `Integer` object, then calling `toString()` on that object.

Alternatively, you can take advantage of [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to let Java handle the "wrapping" for you automatically:

```
Integer id = checkedRadioButton.getId();
String text = id.toString();
```

Note that `getId()` is still returning an `int`, but because you declared the `id` variable to be an `Integer`, Java "boxes" the return value to its wrapper class automatically - hence "autoboxing".

You can also use the static `Integer.toString()` method:

```
String text = Integer.toString(checkedRadioButton.getId())
```

but note that, under the hood, the same operations are being performed here.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was just wondering if I have set the id for the radio button inside the xml file, is this not the same id that getId() returns? Because I have set those ids as strings, and those are the ids I'm trying to get.

Comment: @user3461659 yes and no: the id you set in your XML file is converted to an `int` value at compile time. See the answers to this question for some useful insights: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045131/what-does-view-method-getid-return

Answer (score 0):

beside @drewmore solution you can use also

`String text = String.valueOf(checkedRadioButton.getId());`